# How to minify files individually

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to minify my files in a different directory but keep the same directory structure. I am using ReactJS on separate pages individually. Here is my directory structure.

```
-- src/
     --admin/
          --admin.js
          --users.js
     --a.js
     --b.js
```

Here is how the bundle directory should be:

```
-- dist/
    --admin/
        --admin.min.js
        --users.min.js
    --a.min.js
    --b.min.js
```

As you can see the directory structure is copied to dist directory and all files are minified individually in their designated directory.

Comment: If it is just minification then you could have used some libs like uglify with task runner, no need of webpack

Answer (score 0):

You can use task runners for tasks like that such as Gulp. With this you can include packages where you automate minification into the folders you want. To use Gulp you need to have Node.js installed.